# Logging issue in apache spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Getting below exception while creating KafkaUtils.createStream();
Below is my spark dependency.same thing was working in spark streaming older version 1.5.2

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
    at com.tcs.iux.core.config.RealtimeProcessing.startSpark(RealtimeProcessing.java:78)
    at com.tcs.iux.core.processor.StartRealTimeProcessing.main(StartRealTimeProcessing.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Any reason you're using two different versions for streaming (2.0.0) and kafka-streaming (1.6.2)? Those versions need to be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

[Logging was made private in Spark 2.0](http://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html)

use 2.0.0 version of `spark-streaming-kafka_2.11` to match it with your spark version.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: seems latest spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 version latest is 1..6.2

Comment: I remember building spark assembly few days back and it had spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, may be they stopped publishing it to maven repo, please refer Yuval's answer, it has details about the new names.

Comment: Thanks the issue got resolved by using below dependency

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing between Spark versions, which is never a good idea. You need to be aligned both for Spark Streaming and it's external Kafka driver.

The dependencies have changed a bit. There's now experimental support for Kafka 0.10.0.x. If you're using Kafka 0.8.2.x, you'll need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to try out Kafka 0.10.0.x, you'll need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```